# "Hide Input Source Name" changes to "Show input source name" on every reboot, on Lion

Tags: macos, input-source

I use three keyboard layouts (three input sources), and I chose to show the source in the toolbar (I mean the main bar at the top).

Since I moved to Lion, in addition to the icon for the input source (usually the flag of the country speaking that source) it also shows the name (which takes a lot of precious space). I choose the "Hide Input Source Name" from the menu and the name goes away until I reboot.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried `rm ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Lri
    `rm ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox*`

works, but you need to get the order right, 
first make sure the label is not showing "Hide Input Source Name" 
then remove the files as suggested, I guess it is also necessary to restart as well, then add the keyboards (input sources) back.

But it comes back!

This is a bug or something,

For the record I am using 
Dvorak-Qwerty
U.S.
Persian

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try would be to lock `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.menuextra.textinput.plist` in Finder. (OS X performs atomic saves on preference files so `chmod 600` wouldn't work.)

At least on my account the file contains just a `ModeNameVisible` key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ModeNameVisible</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: thanks, It was locked already but I now made it read only, let's see what happens.

Comment: Nop! comes back again! even when locked and I have only read access!